# How to find all loops in a sequence of numbers using R

Tags: r

**Have** a sequence of numbers.

```
seqNum <- sample(1:15, 30, replace = T)
[1] 10  7  6  5  4  1 15 11  7 15  1  2  3 14  8  3  5 10  8  3  14 8 14  3 14 12 15 12 10 14
```

**Define "Loop"**: From the first number in the sequence, all numbers between **two** repeat number is defined as a loop. For example, the first loop in the given sequence above is "7 6 5 4 1 15 11". Remove it from the sequence then repeat the previous method to find next loop.
Sequence after remove the first loop became:

```
10 15 1 2  3 14  8  3  5 10  8  3  14 8 14  3 14 12 15 12 10 14
```

Second loop is "3 14 8".
Sequence after remove the second loop became:

```
10 15 1 2 5 10  8  3  14 8 14  3 14 12 15 12 10 14
```

Third loop is "10 15 1 2 5".
Sequence after remove the third loop became:

```
8  3  14 8 14  3 14 12 15 12 10 14
```

Fourth loop is "8 3 14".
Sequence after remove the fourth loop became:

```
14 3 14 12 15 12 10 14
```

Fifth loop is "14 12 15 12 10".(Always using 2 closest repeated number)
Sequence after remove the fifth loop became:

```
14 3
```

DONE.

**Note:**

- "loop" must contains at least 3 numbers
- two loop consider to be the same loop if

  1. contains same number
  2. relative order is same, for example loop "1 2 3 4" is same as loop "3 4 1 2" or "4 1 2 3" or "2 3 4 1", but different from loop "1 3 2 4" or "2 1 3 4", etc.

**Want**:
Find all loops in the given sequence and give the count of each unique loop.

**Desired result:**

```
  count            loop
1     1 7-6-5-4-1-15-11
2     2          3-14-8
3     1     10-15-1-2-5
4     1  14-12-15-12-10
```

I understand this is a long question but I will appreciate any hints. Thank you!!

PS: This suppose to search loops on a very long sequence of numbers, say total around 10^8, please use sample(1:1024, 100000, replace = T) to test.

Comment: Can you use `set.seed()` on your sample so that your numbers are repeatible

Comment: Can the numbers 7  6  5  4  1 15 11  7 15  1  2  3 14  8  3  5  which lie between a pair of 10s be a loop?

Comment: @SymbolixAU, I have modified the example sequence a little bit to to show more situations.

Comment: @Rahul, always searching the loop from beginning. Although a pair of 15 do form a loop, but pair of 7 come first and after remove that "7" loop, "15" loop has been broken. Am I answered your question？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following code will find and print all 'loops' working on the example as expected:

```
seqNum <- c(10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1, 15, 11,  7, 15,  1,  2,  3, 14,  8,  3,  5, 10,  8,  3,  14, 8, 14,  3, 14, 12, 15, 12, 10, 14)
loops <- matrix(ncol = 2,nrow = 0, dimnames = list(numeric(0),c("count","loop")))

remove_loop <- function(seqNum) {
  ht <- new.env()
  for(j in 1:length(seqNum)) {
    i <- seqNum[j]
    key <- as.character(i)
    if(exists(key,envir=ht)) {
      lastIdx <- ht[[key]]
      loop <- seqNum[lastIdx:(j-1)]
      if(length(unique(loop)) > 2) {
        return(list(loop=loop,newSeqNum=seqNum[-(lastIdx:j)]))
      }
    }
    ht[[key]] <- j
  }
}

newSeqNum <- seqNum
repeat{
  l <- remove_loop(newSeqNum)
  newSeqNum <- l$newSeqNum
  if(length(l$loop)){
    print(l$loop)
  } else {
    break
  }
}
```

The output is

```
[1]  7  6  5  4  1 15 11
[1]  3 14  8
[1] 10 15  1  2  5
[1]  8  3 14
[1] 14 12 15 12 10
```

It works by repeatedly removing the next loop, i.e. calling the function `remove_loop` on the remaining sequence. The function `remove_loop` works as follows: Using an environment as a hash table (variable `ht`) it keeps track of the last index each number was encountered at. If a number has been seen at least a second time (i.e. has an entry in the hash table) then a 'loop' may have been found. If the number has been seen more than two (say k) times it is true that the first (k-1) occurences did not meet the criteria for a 'loop'. Thus only the current and the last occurence are relevant. The current occurence is at position `j` and the previous occurence can be found in the hash table. If this 'loop' contains at least three distinct number a 'loop' has been found.

**Edit:** The following code counts all the occurences of different loops. Loops are represented in a 'canonical' form by wrapping them around such that they start with the smallest element:

```
repr_loop <- function(l) {
  idx <- which.min(l)
  if(idx != 1) l <- c(l[idx:length(l)],l[1:(idx-1)])
  paste0(l,collapse="-")
}

loops <- data.frame(count=numeric(),loop=character())

newSeqNum <- seqNum
repeat{
  l <- remove_loop(newSeqNum)
  newSeqNum <- l$newSeqNum
  if(length(l$loop)){
    s <- repr_loop(l$loop)
    idx <- match(s,loops[,"loop"])
    if(!is.na(idx)) {
      loops[idx,"count"] <- loops[idx,"count"] + 1
    } else {
      loops <- rbind(loops,data.frame(count=1,loop=s))
    }
  } else {
    break
  }
}
loops
```

which yields the following output

```
> loops
  count            loop
1     1 1-15-11-7-6-5-4
2     2          3-14-8
3     1     1-2-5-10-15
4     1  10-14-12-15-12
```

Comment: Very nice, but does not yet account for the relative order portion of the question.

Comment: True - I was unsure how the "relative order" is supposed to work. Since partial solutions were solicited I thought I'd give the first part a try (unfortunately I don't have enough rep to ask about the "relative order" in a comment). I have given the order some thought and I will soon update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @JonathanvonSchroeder, I have spent a long time to understand your code and learned a lot. I like the first part of loop searching, but the second part of identify the unique loop looks like has some problems. It is not only related to the first and last number of the loop, it related to the order of each segment. I have edited my original question to clarify the "relative order". Could you please give a thought on how to test if two loops are "identical"?

Comment: Yes, it is more clear what you meant by 'relative' order now. I didn't really understand before so the second part was just one approach. I'll have to think about how to 'normalize' the loops. The easiest way will probably be a representation starting with the smallest or largest number, but I'll have to give the wrap-around a little thought.

Comment: @Leon Have a look at my new implementation. It seems to be indeed slightly easier to find a canonical form. - Hope it works now!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

Your data

```
d <- c(10,7,6,5,4,1,15,11,7,15,1,2,3,14,8,3,5,10,8,3,14,8,14,3,14,12,15,12,10,14)
```

I included everything in a function to easily use the code. The main idea is, to search for duplicates, check the length between the first duplicate and the first occurence of the number. If it is euqual or longer than three quit the loop and extract the segment, then update the vector and do all things as long as there are no further duplicates (`while`). I have to say that there could be problems when two loop segments are occuring at the same time in the vector.

```
foo <- function(x){
 d1 <- x
 res <- NULL  # vector for the results
  while(any(duplicated(d1))){
   gr <- which(duplicated(d1))
      for(i in gr){
        # here the magic happens
        pos <- which(d1 == d1[i])
        gr_pos <- which(diff(pos) >= 3)
        pos <- pos[c(gr_pos,gr_pos+1)]
        if(pos[2]-pos[1] >= 3) break
      }
   # extract the "loop" sequences
   extract <- d1[seq(pos[1],pos[2])][-length(seq(pos[1],pos[2]))]
   res <-  append(res,paste(sort(extract), collapse = "-")) # save the loop
   d1 <- d1[-seq(pos[1],pos[2])] # update input vector
   if(length(d1) < 3) break # emergency stop
  }
 data.frame(table(res)) # output
}

foo(d)
              res Freq
1     1-2-5-10-15    1
2 1-4-5-6-7-11-15    1
3  10-12-12-14-15    1
4          3-8-14    2
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, but it gives error. I believe it because of two same number appear at the same time just like you mentioned before.

Comment: @Leon Please update your example data, then we can improve the code for duplicates.